# Can anonymous function be used to defer js on load?

Tags: javascript, deferred-execution, deferred-loading

I just read about deferring js on load. I found Particks article pretty interesting http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html.

I took a look at facebook and googles js code. They are all using anonymous functions so I was wondering whether this is deferring js to load after page is loaded?

```
 (function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

or is Patricks recommendation the only way to really defer loading js after page is loaded?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "defer.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
  }
  if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
  else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

thx, i really appreciate your expertise!

Comment: As far as I understand it, is the fb script only avoiding to load the same script multiple times or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Both will download the script asynchronously and defer the execution after it is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts), but the second script waits with starting to load the script until all other resources (including images!) have been loaded (which seems a bit late to me actually).

> They are all using anonymous functions so I was wondering whether this is deferring js?

No, those [IEFEs](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) are only used to structure the code, they do execute immediately. What does defer the js is the dynamic creation of `<script>` elements.

Comment: What does defer mean in this context. Is it "enough" deferred to say it's good for google page speed optimizations?

Comment: Yes. `defer` basically means "*no need to halt the HTML parser and everything else until the script has been loaded and executed*", which is the thing that google page speed grumps about.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Let me try to explain it:

The First code snippet (`FB`, `G+`) Api for checking whether `script` is present or not and including it. It is called as self executing function.

Note:

```
(function(x){
...
}(x));
```

Is usually syntax for `Self-Executing Anonymous Functions`. Self-invoking functions runs instantly i.e will be executed as soon as it is encountered in the Javascript. They executes as soon as it is encountered by parser(order of execution depends on where you place the function or script containing that) and thus the name self executing.

Your Second Snippet. Creates same functionality but binds it to `window` element and waits till all the window elements(DOM, images, frames, iframes, links, scripts etc) `loads` fully. And then and only then it starts executing your functionality. So its kinda slower. More faster than that is : JQuery's `$(document).ready(`.

To know which load event executes first have a look at My answer on this question: [What will be the sequence of execution of this javascript/Jquery code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989025/what-will-be-the-sequence-of-execution-of-this-javascript-jquery-code/23989387#23989387)

Now again to your point:   **Can anonymous function be used to defer js on load?**

The answer is **NO**, coz it depends where you put your self executing anonymous function. and still it'll be faster than `window.load`.

Hope it helps :). Cheers!